# How do I create middleware for parse and parse_item using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

I am using Scrapy and would like to be able to check my database for a `should_continue` flag and raise a CloseSpider exception if it's false. However, according to the documentation here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html, CloseSpider can only be called from `parse` or `parse_item`.

I could add a function in each `parse` and `parse_item` for each spider, but that goes against DRY principals. Can I somehow create a `parse` and `parse_item` middleware that is always called before those functions are called?

I couldn't get it to trigger using DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE or SPIDER_MIDDLEWARE, whats the correct way to do this?

Comment: create one function and run it in `parse` and `parse_item`. This way you don't repeat yourself - you have only one function - but you use it in two places - `parse` and `parse_item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing Scrapy does when `CloseSpider` is raised is call the `close_spider()` method of the execution engine: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L152-L153

You can just call that method yourself to achieve the same result.

This is also what the CloseSpider extension does: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/closespider.py